# How to mock a Router object and inject into providers array in TestBed configuration

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, router, testbed

I'm trying to create and inject a mocked router object into TestBed configuration but it does not work. Below is the configuration :

```
let mockQuote: QuoteService = new QuoteService(null, null);
let mockOshcStore: OshcStore = new OshcStore(null);
let mockActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute = new ActivatedRoute();
let mockRouter: Router = new Router(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
//let mockRouter: RouterMock = new RouterMock();
//let router:Router;
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: QuoteService, useFactory: () => {
        return mockQuote;
      }
    }, FormBuilder, AppStore,
    {
      provide: OshcStore, useFactory: () => {
        return mockOshcStore;
      }
    },
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, useFactory: () => {
        return mockActivatedRoute;
      }
    },
    {
      provide: Router, useFactory: () => {
        return mockRouter;
      }
    },
    HttpClient, QuoteCISLAdapter
  ],
  declarations: [CreateQuoteComponent]
});
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateQuoteComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

The above works until the 'ActivatedRoute' but stops when it hits the route and gives :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null

  at new Router (../packages/router/src/router.ts:406:30)
```

I also tried the imports array with 'RouterTestingModule' module as well but didn't work too. Any idea to craete a safe mocked Router object?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule#usage-notes

Comment: @maxime1992, I tried this but my component arguments said to be (?,?..then That's why I need to add this into providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually have something like the above at the top of my beforeEach:

```
mockActivatedRoute = {
            url: 'test',
            params: of({ paramOne: 1,paramTwo: 2018 })
        };
```

and then the below in my providers array:

```
{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
```

For route... this assumes you're only using navigate in your component if you're using more you'll need to mock more things:

```
router = {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
        };
```

and then in the providers array:

```
{ provide: Router, useValue: router },
```

Comment: This is activated route, How can I give router like in the same manner?

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Added more details

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I'll let you know if this works. Having some other troubles with JEST!